# How to use marginTop when view wrap to next row?

Tags: react-native

I have an array data , i map the array return `<Button />`, but i find that when the view wrap `<Button />` to next row automatically, there is no spacing each row.

[image]

How do i know what time is the view wrap to next row ? So that i can control margingTop between each row.

I try to add `position: 'relative'` in my `itemBody` style, but there is no any different.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my view code:

```
<Body style={styles.timeBody}>
              {releasedTime.map((value, index) => {     
              const userTime = GetUserTime.getUserHour();              
              const theTime = GetUserTime.getAsiaTime(value, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');
              const hour = theTime.getHours();            
              const minute = (theTime.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + theTime.getMinutes();
              if (userTime < hour) {
                return (
                  <GrayButton key={index}>{`${hour}:${minute}`}</GrayButton>
                );
              }
              return (
                <Button key={index}>{`${hour}:${minute}`}</Button>
              );
              })}
            </Body>
```

Here is my style for wrap:

```
const styles = {
  timeBody: {
    flex: 1, 
    flexDirection: 'row', 
    paddingTop: 5, 
    flexWrap: 'wrap', 
    width: '100%'
  }
};
```

Comment: just include timeBody to marginTop:5 ? what will change?

Comment: If i use marginTop: 5 instead of paddingTop: 5, nothing will be changed. Its the same.

Comment: or use marginTop button style property!!

Comment: Yes ! It is correct ! Why i don't think about that. I'm so stupid...  Any way , can you post it to an answer i will accept it. Thanks for your help @Aboo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add ***marginTop*** on Your **Button** and **customButtons**

```
 <Button style={{marginTop:5}} key={index}>{`${hour}:${minute}`}</Button>
```

Like this also add to customButton like  `<GrayButton/>`